# animate UIButton border thickness

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is it possible to animate the border thickness of a UIButton?

I tried the following but I just get a quick flash between the two thicknesses I'm trying to animate between.

```
//animate border thickness
    UIButton *btn = _barButton;
    CALayer *buttonLayer = [btn layer];

        [buttonLayer setBorderWidth:0.0f];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

            [buttonLayer setBorderWidth:15.0f];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

                [buttonLayer setBorderWidth:2.5f];

            } completion:nil];
        }];
```

EDIT: As per David H's suggestion, this can be done with CABasicAnimation.

```
UIButton *btn = _barButtons;
CALayer *buttonLayer = [btn layer];

//animate border thickness
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.keyPath = @"borderWidth";
animation.fromValue = @0.0;
animation.toValue = @5.0;
animation.duration = 0.25;
[buttonLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but you'll have to code the animation differently. Look at Apple's "Core Animation Programming Guide", and find the section on "CALayer Animatable Properties". You can see that borderWidth is animatable, but you need to use the default implied CABasicAnimation object, described in that document.

I've done this kind of thing in the past - but it was years ago so foggy on the specific details. But you can make it work for sure.